# How can I get the ContainerProperties with Indexes from an existing container in CosmosDB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I created a container with container properties, and this `ContainerProperties` contains indexes.

How can I get back the `ContainerProperties` from cosmos later.
I use following code:

```
FeedIterator<ContainerProperties> resultSet = CosmosDatabase.GetContainerQueryIterator<ContainerProperties>( ($"select * from c where c.id = \"{collectionName}\"") );
FeedResponse<ContainerProperties> queryProperties = resultSet.ReadNextAsync().Result;

ContainerProperties containerProperties = queryProperties.Resource.ToList().FirstOrDefault()
```

There is a `ContainerProperties` and the name is filled correctly, and this is what I want, but the indexes are empty. The `containerProperties.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths` and the `containerProperties.IndexingPolicy.ExcludedPaths`  does not contains any element. But when I created it, it does.

Comment: Which version of the SDK package are you using?

Comment: I use the Azure Cosmos DB .NET SDK Version 3.0.0.1-preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you are using a preview version of the SDK, please update to the [latest GA release](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos), which is `3.0.0` at this time.

On that version, running the code that you shared, returns a `ContainerProperties` instance that has the IndexingPolicy populated.

```
ContainerProperties containerDefinition = new ContainerProperties(new Guid().ToString(), "/id");
containerDefinition.IndexingPolicy.ExcludedPaths.Add(new Cosmos.ExcludedPath()
{
    Path = "/*"
});
ContainerResponse response = await cosmosDatabase.CreateContainerAsync(containerDefinition);
FeedIterator<ContainerProperties> resultSet = cosmosDatabase.GetContainerQueryIterator<ContainerProperties>(($"select * from c where c.id = \"{response.Container.Id}\""));
FeedResponse<ContainerProperties> queryProperties = resultSet.ReadNextAsync().Result;
ContainerProperties containerSettings = queryProperties.Resource.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
Assert.AreEqual(containerDefinition.IndexingPolicy.ExcludedPaths.First().Path, containerSettings.IndexingPolicy.ExcludedPaths.First().Path);
```

Comment: But in your code there is no any index creation! Anyway I will update the driver, and I will try it

Comment: Same effect with newest version as well. The index is not in the container properties

Comment: @GyörgyGulyás I edited the code sample, adding an ExcludedPath during creation also returns the correct value after a query.